# GO terms for non-model organisms

Tags: bioinformatics, rna-sequencing, blast

I have a list of differentially expressed genes from an RNA-Seq experiment in *Xenopus laevis* that I'm looking to functionally annotate with GO-terms. As *X.laevis* is not listed in DAVID it seems I have 2 options:

- BLAST my DE genes against a database with GO terms (human/mouse) to look for orthologs
- Use a program that assigns GO from BLAST results, such as Blast2GO

I've been trying with Blast2GO recently, but find if very slow and generally lacking - does anyone have any experience doing GO in *Xenopus* or other non-model organisms?

Comment: interesting question, but no experience doing this from me. Have you tried BioStars.org?

Answer (score 2):

I've done a functional annotation of a non-model, and used Blast2Go with fine results.

Specifically, I took all of my proteins and queried again the [NCBI non redundant (nr) protein database](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/refseq/) using [mpiBLAST](http://www.mpiblast.org/), then I analyzed this output using Blast2GO (B2G4PIPE) and a local B2G Database.

Answer (score 2):

blast2go is on the verge of getting commercialized (as they have started selling PRO versions) and my previous experience was not so good with it.

I used IntrProScan to associate GO terms with the transcripts, it ran long but it reported all the possible sequence features.

To use these custom annotation was tricky for visualization, but thanks to BiNGO, I was able to do it flawlessly. For future use I have documented it here, http://infoplatter.blogspot.in/2014/04/gene-ontology-go-enrichment-analysis-in.html

Good luck!!

Answer (score 2):

Updating this thread to include [EnTAP](https://entap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), (Eukaryotic Non-model Transcriptome Annotation Pipeline) which wraps protein domain assignment, orthologous gene family assessment, Gene Ontology term assignment, and KEGG pathway annotation into a single tool. I have used it for annotating sequences from divergent groups of non-model species.

See the paper in [Molecular Ecology Resources](https://doi.org/10.1111/1755-0998.13106).